# How to save a token in a local storage (or cookie)?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am trying to implement a login function in an app. Currently, I could register a login, generate a jwt token. However, I do not know how to store this token in a cookie (or local storage). I have a middleware that would require a user to send a token in each request which is private. In postman, I could put 'x-auth-token' and a token in a header. Many of the tutorials use passport, cookie-parser which seemed kinda complicated. Are there any other easier ways? I saw in the express document that there were `res.cookie('x-auth-token', token);` available too, I tried it but it didn't work. I also tried `window.localStorage.setItem('x-auth-token', token);`, still didn't work.

I have tried something super simple which is to simply put a token in a localStorage. `window.localStorage.setItem('x-auth token', token);` However, it didn't work.

auth

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');

// middleware function, next so it moves on to the next middlware
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  //get the token from header
  const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

  //Check if not token
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, authorization denied' });
  }

  //Verify token if exist
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Token is not valid' });
  }
};
```

posts.js

```
// @ route    POST api/users
// @desc      Register User
// @access    Public
router.post(
  '/',
  [
    check('name', 'Name is required')
      .not()
      .isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Please include a valid email').isEmail(),
    check(
      'password',
      ' Please enter a password with 6 or more characters'
    ).isLength({ min: 6 })
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: errors.array()
      });
    }
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    try {
      // See if user exists, have to be unique
      let user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (user) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'User already exists' }] });
      }
      // Get users gravatar
      const avatar = gravatar.url(email, {
        s: '200',
        r: 'pg',
        d: 'mm'
      });
      user = new User({
        name,
        email,
        avatar,
        password
      });

      //encrypt password
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
      // anything that return a promise, we have to put await !!
      await user.save();
      //return jsonwebtoken
      const payload = {
        user: {
          id: user.id
        }
      };

      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        config.get('jwtSecret'),
        { expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 100 },
        (err, token) => {
          // window.localStorage.setItem('x-auth-token', token);
          res.json({ token });
          res.cookie('x-auth-token', token);
          // req.flash('You seccessfully registered your account');
          // res.redirect('/user/login');
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
  }
);
```

main.handlebars

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/register.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/804afe4c6e.js"></script>

    {{!-- for auto-reload --}}
    <script src="/reload/reload.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascript/main.js"></script>


    <title>Idea Share</title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar bg-dark">
        <h1><a href="/">Idea Share</a></h1>
        <ul>
            <a href="/signup">
                <li>Sign up</li>
            </a>
            <a href="/signup">
                <li>Log in</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        {{{body}}}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

register.handlebars

```
<div class="height-container">
    <div class="vertical-align">
        <div class="register-form">
            <h1>Create your account</h1>
            <form class="form" action="/api/users" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" requried>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                </div>  

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" minlength="6">
                </div>
                <input onclick="loginUser()" type="submit" value="Create account" class="button green-button" />
            </form>
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="/signin">Sign in</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

post.handlebars

```
<div class="height-container">
    <div class="vertical-align">
        <div class="idea-form">
            <h1>Share your idea</h1>
            <form class="form" action="/api/posts" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="What is your idea?" name="title" requried>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Let us know more detail. What is the story. How did you come up with it? 
Why do you think people would need it etc" name="body">
                </div>
                <input "type=" submit" value="Post" class="button green-button" />

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are executing the above code on the node JS. node doesn't have windows object. localStorage is defined in the window object. You have to set the token from the client side.

Comment: If you want to store token in cookies then you can set it from nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save item to localstorage in nodejs. First sent your Response to client side and save the the res token to Browser local storage using `localStorage.setItem('x-auth-token', token);`.

on client side use your token as :-

```
http.post('/', userCredentials).then(response => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('x-auth-token', response.token)
  }
  );
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but could you explain more clearly about it? I tried making a submit button to trigger the event handler that includes your code above but got `Reference Error: http is not defined`. At the register submit button in a form, I put `<input onclick="loginUser()" type="submit" value="Create account" class="button green-button" />` . Then for main.js(client side javascript), I added your code like `function loginUser() {
  http.post('/', userCredentials).then(response => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('x-auth-token', response.token);
  });
}`

Comment: can u please update the question with some more client side code?
also are you using any clientside frameworks?

Comment: sure, I'll update it. Clientside frameworks? I'm using handlebars, is it one of them?

Comment: I havent used handlebars but try including this ``var http = require('http');`` in script

Comment: script? you meant the front-end script? but isn't require the node syntax?

Comment: your main.js file
can u add it here